# isc-dhcp-serverの起動時の実行登録

Tags: debian, systemd, dhcp

### 目的

OS起動後にDHCPサーバーを自動的に実行させたい。
DHCPサーバーを機能させること自体はできましたが、systemdを使用してのサービス起動に失敗してしまいます。
OS起動後にSystemdを使用してStartすると成功します。
おそらく、Systemdの登録設定ファイルであるisc-dhcp-server.service（自作ファイル）において、なんらかの起動待ちをしなければならないと予想しておりますが、どういう記述をすればよいかが分かりません。
ご教示をお願いします。

### 環境

OS：Debian11

### インストール

```bash
apt install isc-dhcp-server
```

インストール後に/etc/init.d以下に配置される。

```bash
/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server
```

### 設定

関連設定ファイル
/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server

```bash
# Defaults for isc-dhcp-server (sourced by /etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server)

# Path to dhcpd's config file (default: /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf).
DHCPDv4_CONF=/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
#DHCPDv6_CONF=/etc/dhcp/dhcpd6.conf

# Path to dhcpd's PID file (default: /var/run/dhcpd.pid).
#DHCPDv4_PID=/var/run/dhcpd.pid
#DHCPDv6_PID=/var/run/dhcpd6.pid

# Additional options to start dhcpd with.
#   Don't use options -cf or -pf here; use DHCPD_CONF/ DHCPD_PID instead
#OPTIONS=""

# On what interfaces should the DHCP server (dhcpd) serve DHCP requests?
#   Separate multiple interfaces with spaces, e.g. "eth0 eth1".
INTERFACESv4="eth0"
#INTERFACESv6=""
```

/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf

```bash
# dhcpd.conf
#
# Sample configuration file for ISC dhcpd
#

default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;

ddns-update-style none;

subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 192.168.1.10 192.168.1.100;
  option routers 192.168.1.4;
  option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
  option broadcast-address 192.168.1.255;
}
```

### 設定動作確認

```bash
sudo /etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server start
```

DHCPサーバーが動作していることを確認しました。

### サービス起動設定

以下のファイルを作成し、/etc/systemd/system以下に配置。
isc-dhcp-server.service

```bash
[Unit]
Description=DHCP server - isc-dhcp-server
Before=network.target
Before=nss-lookup.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server start
ExecStop=/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server stop
Type=forking
PIDFile=/var/run/dhcpd.pid

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

サービスを有効化

```bash
systemctl enable isc-dhcp-server.service
```

```bash
$ systemctl list-unit-files --type=service | grep isc-dhcp
isc-dhcp-sever.service    enabled  enabled
```

### OS起動時

OS起動時にサービス実行が失敗します。

```bash
$ systemctl status isc-dhcp-server.service 
● isc-dhcp-server.service - DHCP server - isc-dhcp-server
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/isc-dhcp-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2024-03-21 16:15:29 JST; 1min 21s ago
    Process: 960 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 120ms

Mar 21 16:15:27 linaro-alip dhcpd[1090]: bugs on either our web page at www.isc.org or in the README file
Mar 21 16:15:27 linaro-alip dhcpd[1090]: before submitting a bug.  These pages explain the proper
Mar 21 16:15:27 linaro-alip dhcpd[1090]: process and the information we find helpful for debugging.
Mar 21 16:15:27 linaro-alip dhcpd[1090]: 
Mar 21 16:15:27 linaro-alip dhcpd[1090]: exiting.
Mar 21 16:15:29 linaro-alip isc-dhcp-server[960]: Starting ISC DHCPv4 server: dhcpdcheck syslog for diagnostics. ...
Mar 21 16:15:29 linaro-alip isc-dhcp-server[1140]:  failed!
Mar 21 16:15:29 linaro-alip isc-dhcp-server[1141]:  failed!
Mar 21 16:15:29 linaro-alip systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 21 16:15:29 linaro-alip systemd[1]: Failed to start DHCP server - isc-dhcp-server.
```

手動で起動すると、成功します。

```bash
$ systemctl start isc-dhcp-server.service 
$ systemctl status isc-dhcp-server.service 
● isc-dhcp-server.service - DHCP server - isc-dhcp-server
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/isc-dhcp-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2024-03-21 16:18:44 JST; 3s ago
    Process: 2015 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 2030 (dhcpd)
        CPU: 148ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/isc-dhcp-server.service
             └─2030 /usr/sbin/dhcpd -4 -q -cf /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf eth0

Mar 21 16:18:42 linaro-alip isc-dhcp-server[2015]: Launching IPv4 server only.
Mar 21 16:18:42 linaro-alip dhcpd[2030]: Wrote 10 leases to leases file.
Mar 21 16:18:42 linaro-alip dhcpd[2030]: Server starting service.
Mar 21 16:18:42 linaro-alip dhcpd[2030]: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.1.14 from 00:03:30:20:c0:04 (00033020C004) via eth0
Mar 21 16:18:42 linaro-alip dhcpd[2030]: DHCPACK on 192.168.1.14 to 00:03:30:20:c0:04 (00033020C004) via eth0
Mar 21 16:18:44 linaro-alip isc-dhcp-server[2015]: Starting ISC DHCPv4 server: dhcpd.
```

Comment: 参考: [systemd: start service at boot time after network is really up (for WoL purpose)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54300998)

Comment: 参考にさせていただいたのですが、うまく機能しませんでした。

Answer (score 0):

isc-dhcp-server をインストールするとデフォルトでは init.d 以下にサービス起動用のスクリプトが配置されるようなので、 sysv-rc-conf を使うとよいかもしれません。

[パッケージ: sysv-rc-conf](https://packages.debian.org/ja/bullseye/sysv-rc-conf)

> #### 端末用 SysV init ランレベル設定ツール
>
> `sysv-rc-conf` は、"`/etc/rc{runlevel}.d/`" シンボリックリンク管理用の端末 GUI を供給します。二種類のインターフェイスが付属してきます。一つは単にサービスを オンオフできるだけのもの、もう一方は、シンボリックをより精密に調整できるものです。ほとんどのランレベル設定プログラムと違い、現在いるランレベルだけでなく、 あらゆるランレベルの起動スクリプトを編集できます。

必要なパッケージをインストール

```
$ sudo apt install sysv-rc-conf -y
```

サービスの起動を有効にする

```
$ sudo sysv-rc-conf isc-dhcp-server on
```

参考:
[サービスの管理・設定 (Ubuntu)](https://www.linuxmania.jp/ubuntu_service.html)

Comment: apt install時点でFailとなり進みませんでした。